# Records randomly get duplicated when added or edited.

Tags: 2013, duplicate

For some reason when a certain user is adding a record, it duplicates it three times. This also happens randomly when they edit the record.

Some get duplicated while some don't. There is no workflows or event handlers.

Why is that happening? 
[image]

Comment: Are they using Quick Edit? Check the Modified Value and see it happened same time.

Comment: opens the record to edit, and it shows it was duplicated at the same time... When I search the JPP 17079318, only one record displays, but these three duplicates have three different IDs

Comment: Do you use Custom New/Edit Form?

Comment: YES. it is a cascading one for my dropdowns, and one to customize how the form looks. do u have a email so I can send it 2 you?

Comment: anyone have a idea?

Comment: It seems form is posting back data multiple times. You can run fiddler and check this out.

Comment: Above is the cascading script, do you think this is the issue?

Comment: Please delete comment and update answer wit code

Comment: @AmalHashim do you think the cascading code below is the issue?

Comment: Not sure. You can try removing it and verify.

Comment: I was thinking about adding a unique value option so there wont be any duplicated but in order to apply that I have to remove the duplicates first.... do you know a good way to filter and see what records in my column are duplicates so I can delete those?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sites/jppdatabase/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sites/jppdatabase/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "EngListT",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Muni",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "Muni",
    childColumn: "EngArea",
    selectSingleOption: true,
    debug: true
  });<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sites/jppdatabase/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sites/jppdatabase/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "EngListT",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Muni",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "Muni",
    childColumn: "EngArea",
    selectSingleOption: true,
    debug: true
  });
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "WCListT",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Muni",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "Muni",
    childColumn: "WC",
    selectSingleOption: true,
  });
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "AreaList",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Muni",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "Muni",
    childColumn: "Area",
  });
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "TaxDistrictList",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Muni",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "Muni",
    childColumn: "TaxDistrict",
    selectSingleOption: true,
  });
});
</script>
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "WCListT",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Muni",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "Muni",
    childColumn: "WC",
    selectSingleOption: true,
  });
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "AreaList",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Muni",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "Muni",
    childColumn: "Area",
  });
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "TaxDistrictList",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Muni",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "Muni",
    childColumn: "TaxDistrict",
    selectSingleOption: true,
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: just formatted the code